# How can I replace dict in column by they keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Dict
{a:b}
{a:b, c:d}
{a:b}
```

How can I replace that by this:

```
Dict
1
2
1
```

I am trying with:

```
df[df['model']=='bagging']['params'].keys()
```

But doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean replace it by the number of keys in the dictionary? If so, all you have to do is just set the column equal to len(keys)

Comment: Do you mean `d = [{a:b},{a:b, c:d},{a:b}]` `d = [len(s) for s in d]`?

Comment: I think so, the only difference is that here it's a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem you're asking about, but I'm assuming you're looking for the length of the dictionary in each row. This should do just fine:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Dict': {'a':'b'}}, {'Dict': {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}}, {'Dict': {'a':'b'}}])

df['len'] = df['Dict'].apply(len)
```

Results in:

```
                   Dict  len
0            {'a': 'b'}    1
1  {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}    2
2            {'a': 'b'}    1
```